# Can't able to load millions of records from ms access database

Tags: php, ms-access-2007, phpexcel, query-performance

I am trying to fetch 14,00,000 records from the ms access database. But I can't load that much records at a single time. it will exceeds memory and it will give an error. I want compare this records with my excel sheets records then will create new excel sheet to write matched records. During this process it gives an error like memory allocation exceeds. Please suggest me any possible way to do so.

Comment: Have you tried any approach already ?

Comment: You could import the spreadsheet into the database then do the necessary queries

Comment: I am matching records with the PHP, can you please suggest me how do I use MS Access database to process my excel  data, Because I am going to check each excel record with these 14,00,000 records

Comment: If you use a loop like `while ($row = fetch_row($result))` it shouldn't need to load all the records at a single time. But comparing 14M rows will take a long time.

Comment: yes, it does take long time and meanwhile it also gives an error like memory exceeds...

Comment: Given that you've not shown any code to indicate what you're trying to do, it's almost impossible for us to guess... how are you loading the file? Is it a real Excel file or a CSV file? How are you comparing the records?

Comment: What are you dealing with `PHP`? This is an `MS-Access` task. Import like Jeff suggestest (`external data`.--> `import Excel`--> `create a linked table`, then query the data. If you need more performance, change backend to a more powerfull `dbms` like `MS-SQL` or `MySQL`.)